# How to import an XML Database into HBASE

Tags: xml, database, import, hbase

I am starting to study HBASE and I have a task but I don t know from where I have to start it.
I have an XML database and I should import it to HBASE.

Sample file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/e47itzrqg36kuci/pub-venues.xml

I know how to create a table and import csv files into it. But the problem is, the csv files have lines and the number of fields in each is constant, I mean even if there is no value the field still there between the commas.
Please help me and tell me where to find some information about it. Thank you.